Passing secrets to build-push-action by names
I want to add secrets to build-push-action by names. This is how I done with one secret:
Define a reusable workflow:

## inputs definition
on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      build_repo_secret_name:
        description: 'Build Arguments (format: "secret_name")'
        required: false
        type: string
        default: ''
      ## some other inputs


# the action i am mentioning
- name: Docker build and push
    id: build-and-push
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v5
    with:
    context: ${{ inputs.context }}
    push: ${{ inputs.push }}
    platforms: ${{ inputs.build_platforms }}
    tags: ${{ inputs.tags }}
    target: ${{ inputs.target }}
    file: ${{ inputs.dockerfile }}
    no-cache: ${{ inputs.no_cache }}
    provenance: ${{ inputs.provenance }}
    load: ${{ inputs.load }}
    build-args: ${{ inputs.build_args }}
    secrets: ${{ inputs.build_repo_secret_name  != '' && format('"{0}={1}"', inputs.build_repo_secret_name, secrets[inputs.build_repo_secret_name]) || '' }}


I then reuse the workflow with build_repo_secret_name=A_SECRET_NAME.
Now I want to be able to use multiple secret names, such as build_repo_secret_name=A_SECRET_NAME_1,A_SECRET_NAME_2. How should I modify the "Docker build and push" action to consume the new format of build_repo_secret_name?

You will have to introduce two inputs:
build_repo_secret_name_1
build_repo_secret_name_2

and handle two condition same way you did a single condition:
build_repo_secret_name_1 != '' && build_repo_secret_name_2 != ''
build_repo_secret_name_1 != ''


Hi @Delta, your suggestion can work, but could not generalize to multiple secrets :). Thanks.
